# Como puedo crear un menu swipe con jquery que se abra desde abajo

Tags: jquery, menú

Busco un menú en Jquery que se pueda abrir y cerrar con deslizamiento arriba y abajo e probado con varios ejemplos pero no encuentro lo que estoy buscando dejo unas fotos por si me podéis ayudar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: con jquery? pero esa es una aplicación de teléfono, o especifica cuál tecnología estas usando

Comment: ¿Qué ejemplos ha probado?¿cómo no te funcionan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final solucione con lo que encontre en esta pagina

[Slide and swipe menu](http://joanclaret.github.io/slide-and-swipe-menu/#)

Gracias a todos por vuestras repuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo a ver si te sirve, saludos:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#demo_menu1").sidebar();
  $("ul#demo_menu2").sidebar({
    position: "right",
    callback: {
      item: {
        enter: function() {
          $(this).find("a").animate({
            color: "red"
          }, 250);
        },
        leave: function() {
          $(this).find("a").animate({
            color: "white"
          }, 250);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $("ul#demo_menu3").sidebar({
    position: "top",
    open: "click"
  });
  $("ul#demo_menu4").sidebar({
    position: "bottom"
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sliding-Sidebar-Menu-jQuery-Sidebar/css/dark-glass/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sliding-Sidebar-Menu-jQuery-Sidebar/src/jquery.sidebar.js"></script>



<body>
  <ul id="demo_menu1">
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Write</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Less</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Do</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="demo_menu2">
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Write</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Less</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Do</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="demo_menu3">
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Write</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Less</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Do</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="demo_menu4">
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Write</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Less</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Do</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <b style="font-size:80px;position:absolute;top:42%;left:35%;"><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sliding-Sidebar-Menu-jQuery-Sidebar.html" style="color:#000;">Download this plugin</a></b> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>
```